# how to store more numbers of strings in an string array

Tags: c++, string, vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    long int a1[1000000];
    string a[1000000];
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        a[i]=" ";
    int n;
    cout << "enter the value of n";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a1[i];
        v.push_back(a1[i]);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    char ch[100];
    int i=0;
    do { 
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            ch[j] = v[j] + '0';
            // cout<<ch[j];
        }
        int j=3;
        int k=0;
        for(int l=0; l<n; l++)
        {
            a[i] = a[i] + ch[l];
        }
        cout << a[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
    cout << endl << i;
}
```

i want to store all my permutations in an string array but i am unable to store  >8!(40320) i.e 9! onwards, if i am declaring **string a[1000000]**  it showing error in dev c++ can one  any explain me how to store it an string array speifically(as i want this string code  in another code which makes it easier)  greater than 9! or upto 15!

Comment: You want to store up to `15!` strings in a container? Are you sure you know how large that is and how much storage it would require?

Comment: @Blastfurnace  using container may require large memory ,i want upto 10^15 storage as i want in doing spoj

Comment: Seriously, get out a calculator and estimate how much RAM/address space is needed for over 1.3 trillion `std::string` objects and their contents. If you are doing this for a spoj problem you are probably attempting a ridiculously impractical brute-force solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack overflow.

The stack is too small for such number of elements. You need to use the heap (using `operator new`). Or just use `std::vector`.

For example, you can replace

```
string a[1000000];
```

with

```
std::vector< std::string > a( 1000000 );
```

Same for the `long int`.

Comment: i dont think the heap will be enough either for 15!

Comment: @meh using container may require large memory ,i want upto 10^15 storage is there any alternative

Comment: @user1670364 - you should do some research. There are different technics for this. Also, it depends on what you're trying to do. It's a complicated task.

Answer (score 0):

Write to a file flushing it regularly.
Cache the required few in memory.